# How do you delete classes from a Jade database

Tags: jade-platform

When I try to delete a class using the "Remove" option in the Jade class browser, I get the error:

"Class xxx cannot be deleted because:
Classes in an SDS Primary database cannot be deleted from the current schema context".

How can I remove a class?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of an SDS environment, you need to version the schema before you can remove a class (using the 'Remove' option via the IDE for the latest schema version).

The re-org used to transition schema versions is then replayed on the SDS environment, as part of which its cached metadata is refreshed to reflect structural changes.  I believe class removals is included with this (even if there's no persistent instances), because it'd need to discard the redundant class number.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the Jade Schema Loader, with a command file.

According to the [JADE Schema Load User's Guide](https://www.jadeworld.com/docs/jade-2018/Default.htm#resources/jadscmload/ch1usingschemaloadutility/commandfile.htm), the syntax for the command file is:

```
JadeCommandFile
JadeVersionNumber 7.1.00
Commands
Delete Class ErewhonInvestmentsModelSchema::TenderSale
```

And you load it on your database server using:

`jade.exe schema=RootSchema app=JadeSchemaLoader path=d:\jade\system ini=d:\jade\myjade.ini startAppParameters commandFile=d:\temp\DeleteClass.jcf loadStyle=currentSchemaVersion`

Be sure to shutdown your database before running the command, or it will not run.